# Timeout not working with apache.cxf for aysnchronous calls

Tags: web-services, soap, timeout, cxf

We are on apache CXF v3.1.  I'm making API calls to a SOAP based server.  I used to make synchronous calls and the following logic worked just fine for timeouts:

```
    URL url = MyClient.class.getClassLoader().getResource("service.wsdl");

    // create service
    PaymentPortTypeService service = new PaymentPortTypeService(url);

    // Set executor for async response
    service.setExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);

    /*
     * Handlers are used to set the security headers on the SOAP envelope.
     */
    PaymentsHeaderHandlerResolver hResolver = new PaymentsHeaderHandlerResolver(userId, password);
    service.setHandlerResolver(hResolver);

    // create client
    client = service.getPaymentPortTypeSoap11();

    BindingProvider bp = ((BindingProvider) client);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, vBaseUrl);

    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client c = ClientProxy.getClient(client);

    ((ClientImpl)c).setSynchronousTimeout(30000);

    AsyncHTTPConduit httpConduit = (AsyncHTTPConduit) c.getConduit();
    httpConduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(1000);
    httpConduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(30000);
    httpConduit.getClient().setAllowChunking(false);
```

After we have moved to asynchronous HTTP, the timeouts don't seem to work anymore.  Can you spot what I might be doing wrong?

Please note that we have the following in pom.xml to help generate the async interfaces:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/service.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-asyncMethods</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please share your solution for this problem.

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to use CXF specific code, you can set timeout via binding properties:

```
bp.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", 30000);
bp.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", 10000);
```

Please note, the `javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout` and `javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout` are different to `BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT` and `BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT`